# how to use buttons on telegram bot made with telethon

Tags: bots, telegram, telethon

this is the code

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="opzioni"))
async def handler(event):
bottoni = [
    [  
        Button.inline("prima opzione", b"1"), 
        Button.inline("seconda opzione", b"2")
    ],
    [
        Button.inline("terza opzione", b"3"), 
        Button.inline("quarta opzione", b"4")
    ],
    [
        Button.inline("quinta opzione", b"5")
    ]
]

await bot.send_message("tag",".       --queste sono le opzioni--       .", buttons= bottoni)
```

and i want it to do something when i click a button, but i don't have the minimum idea how to do it.

let's say we have 10 photos and one button after i enter a number sends tot photos. how do i do it?

Comment: See the [documentation for `events.CallbackQuery`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.callbackquery.CallbackQuery). This is how you can react to the data being `b"1"`, `b"2"`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.on(events.CallbackQuery())
async def callback(event):
    if event.data == b'1':
        event.edit('your photo')
    elif event.data == b'2':
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?